# Reference for a mixed variational formulation of the heat equation

Tags: functional-analysis, partial-differential-equations, functional-equations, finite-element-method, parabolic-pde

I'm reading an article in which the authors present a "well-known" mixed variational formulation of the heat equation. If $\Omega$ is a bounded domain in $\mathbb{R}^n$, $n=1,2,3$, and we consider $T>0$, the heat equation reads as follows:

Find a function $u$ such that:
$$u_t - \triangle u = f \quad\text{in }\Omega\times(0,T),$$
$$u=0 \quad\text{in }\partial\Omega\times(0,T),$$
$$u(\cdot,0) = g \quad\text{in } \Omega.$$

By introducing the gradient of $u$ as a new variable (i.e. $\sigma=\nabla u$) and by setting $V=L^2(\Omega)$ and $H=H(\text{div},\Omega):=\{\boldsymbol{w}\in(L^2(\Omega))^n : \text{div}\boldsymbol{w}\in L^2(\Omega)\}$, we can rewrite the heat equation in the following mixed variational formulation:

Find $(u,\sigma):(0,T)\to V\times H$ such that
$$(u_t,v) - (\text{div}\sigma,v) = (f,v) \qquad \forall v\in V,\; \forall t\in(0,T),$$
$$(\sigma,\chi) + (u,\text{div}\chi) = 0 \qquad \forall \chi\in H,\; \forall t\in(0,T),$$
$$u(\cdot,0) = g,$$

where $(\cdot,\cdot)$ denotes the usual $L^2(\Omega)$ inner product.

I understand how to deduce the mixed variational formulation, it's actually just applying a Green's formula and the fact that $u=0$ in $\partial\Omega\times(0,T)$, but now I'm having a hard time finding a reference in which it is showed the well-posedness of this formulation (that is, existence and uniqueness of solution).

I assume such reference exists since the article I'm reading states it is a "well-known" mixed formulation, but the article doesn't mention a reference for this subject, and I've been looking for a few days with no success and that's why I'm asking for this here. If anyone know a reference for this and can share it with me I'd really appreciate it.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: This mixed formulation is better known under the name *weak solution*. See [here](https://www.math.ucdavis.edu/~hunter/pdes/ch6.pdf).

Comment: I'd suggest checking out this [book](https://link.springer.com/book/10.1007%2F978-3-319-03695-3) if you want an introduction or [this one](https://link.springer.com/book/10.1007/978-3-642-36519-5) and the references  tehre if you want to know more. They do not deal with the time dependent problem that much but can provide some insight to the mixed formulation business.